# Meaning of the phrase get with up

Tags: phrase-meaning

In the movie Flight Plan (2005) , when the pilot was directing his crew to look for Jodie Foster's daughter , he said sth like , " get the lights up..." . I want to know the meaning of the phrase . Does it mean turning on the lights? I am afraid , I may have misheard it. Pls help.

Comment: We'll need more context. It could refer to placing physical lights on poles; it could  refer to turning dimmable lights to their highest illumination.

Answer (score 2):

[Flightplan 2005 Script](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=flightplan)

> ...
>   I was holding her hand when we took off.
>   Please...
>   You've got to help her.
>   **Get the lights up.**
>   Get every passenger seated.
>   No one in the toilets. No exception.

So the pilot is directing someone to make the lights brighter.
Normally they would say **"turn the lights on"**, but there are always some lights on in a plane and they can be turned "up" or "down", brighter or dimmer. So more often it would be **"turn the lights up"**.

Since the context is someone giving orders, the word **"get"** is stronger and more demanding than **"turn"**, which gives more urgency and importance to the action.

**"Get the lights up!"** *= A command to make lights brighter with urgency.*